# Diferencias en uso entre "que" y "el/la/lo/los/las que"

Tags: gramática

Hasta ahora todavía no entiendo al cien por cien cuándo introducir "que" vs "la que" en oraciones.

Tengo la impresión de que la forma "la que" es más precisa que la forma sin pronombres (especialmente cuando hay muchos objetos y se tiene que precisar). Se puede traducir como "the one which". Pero tengo la impresión de que a veces ambas formas con el mismo significado se pueden usar. Y al usar solo "que" también se puede traducir como "which". No obstante, en la mayoría de los casos yo mismo uso la forma con pronombres porque siento que al usarla me siento más seguro. Unos ejemplos que yo construí:

"*La casa **que** compramos es nueva.*"

"*La casa **la que** compramos es nueva.*"

"*Hay un proyecto **que** necesitamos terminar antes de esta noche.*"

"*Hay un proyecto **el que** necesitamos terminar antes de esta noche.*"

También observaba que en el caso de la forma con pronombres a veces se usan las comas y en algunos casos no:

"*Mi tía, **la que** es profesora, viene a visitarme hoy día.*"

"*La mujer con **la que** tuvimos la entrevista es Rosa.*"

1. ¿Cómo definir cuál forma se tiene que usar?
2. ¿Cuándo no es necesario usar la forma con pronombres ("el que")?
3. ¿Cuándo se necesita usar las comas?

Quiero añadir - sé que "***que***" no se usa en estos casos después de las preposiciones "sin", "por" y "para". Aquí las razones son claras.

P.D. Por adelantado les agradezco a todos ustedes los que corrijan errores en mi letra si haya algunos, o en gramática o en uso de palabras o en algo más.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- "La casa que compramos es nueva." CORRECTO
- "La casa la que compramos es nueva." INCORRECTO
- "Hay un proyecto que necesitamos terminar antes de esta noche." CORRECTO
- "Hay un proyecto el que necesitamos terminar antes de esta noche." INCORRECTO

Después de sustantivos, "el que" y "la que" (y sus respectivos plurales) solo funcionan como aposición, entre comas:

- La casa, la que compramos ayer, es nueva.
- El proyecto, el que necesitamos terminar antes de esta noche, es muy complejo.

Después de preposiciones, siempre pueden funcionar "el que" y "la que" (y sus plurales). Alternativamente, "que" solo funciona con cosas y "quien", con personas:

- La mujer con la que tuvimos la entrevista es Rosa. CORRECTO
- La mujer con que tuvimos la entrevista es Rosa. INCORRECTO
- La mujer con quien tuvimos la entrevista es Rosa. CORRECTO
- El programa con el que hicimos la entrevista no funcionaba. CORRECTO
- El programa con que hicimos la entrevista no funcionaba. CORRECTO
- El programa con quien hicimos la entrevista no funcionaba. INCORRECTO

Comment: Gracias, tengo entendido como usarlo. Quisiera también verificar si entiendo las diferencias en significado. "Tengo la impresión de que la forma "la que" es más precisa que la forma sin pronombres (especialmente cuando hay muchos objetos y se tiene que precisar)" - esto es correcto?

Comment: No, no es correcto.

Comment: Entonces, cuál es la diferencia en el significado entre "El programa con el que hicimos la entrevista no funcionaba." y "El programa con que hicimos la entrevista no funcionaba."?

Comment: No hay diferencia.